# Smallest $n$ such that $S_n$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $C_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The Cayley's theorem tells us that every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of some $S_n$

I have no idea how to go on about this question. I can list every elements of $S_1 , S_2, S_3, ... $ but I'm guessing that's not how it wants me to do it. I also have to find it for $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ and $S_3 \times S_3$ but could anyone please explain the concept using the $C_5$ example? And maybe I will be able to try the rest myself.

Thank you.

Comment: $C_5$ case is clearly $S_5$ just by inspection but the method doesn't really generalise.

Comment: In general, for an integer $k,$ it is not so easy to decide the smallest $n$ such that $S_{n}$ contains an element of order $k,$ though it can be done. However, when $k$ is prime, the problem simplifies a lot.

Comment: @JackYoon just be inspection of what? The result is not hard, but does require some theory.

Answer (score 3):

Let be $a\in S_n$, $a^5=e$, $a\ne e$. By the theorem of Lagrange, $5\,\big|\,n!$ and we conclude that $n\ge 5$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

An element of $\;S_n\;$ has order $\;p\,,\,\,p\;$ a prime, iff it is a product of disjoint $\;p$-cycles, for example $\;(123)\;,\;\;(123)(345)\;$ are elements of order 3 in $\;S_6\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for the first two (third you do it yourself) - look at the permutations $\sigma=( 1 2 3 4 5)$ for $C_5$ and $(12),(34),(56)$ for $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.